# Haskell count elements in a list tail recursion

Tags: list, haskell, count, tail-recursion

I have to get the amount of a `Card` in a list of cards through tail recursion. I was given the following code:

```
amountCard :: Int -> Card -> [Card] -> Int
```

My attempt so far:

```
amountCard n c [] = n
amountCard n k (x:xs) = if k == x then amountCard (n+1) k xs else amountCard n k xs
```

Did I use tail recursion here?

Comment: You better use *guards* than `if-then-else`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this [*Wikipedia* article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) says:

> [A] tail call is a **subroutine call** performed as the **final action
>   of a procedure**. If a tail call might lead to the **same subroutine**
>   being called again later in the call chain, the subroutine is said to
>   be **tail-recursive**, which is a special case of recursion. Tail
>   recursion (or tail-end recursion) is particularly useful, and often
>   easy to handle in implementations.

(formatting added)

Now if you use an `if`-`then`-`else` and nothing after that, you know that the body of the `then` and `else` clause will be the **last things the "procedure" will do**. Since in the body of these `then` and `else` clauses are simple *calls* (there is **no "post processing"** like `1 + (amountCard n k xs)`), **yes** this is indeed tail-recursion.

I would however say that it is more elegant to use *guards* than an `if`-`then`-`else` structure:

```
amountCard n c [] = n
amountCard n k (x:xs) | k == x = amountCard (n+1) k xs
                      | otherwise = amountCard n k xs
```

Furthermore in Haskell usually the *wildcard pattern* is used if a variable is of no importance, like:

```
amountCard n _ [] = n
amountCard n k (x:xs) | k == x = amountCard (n+1) k xs
                      | otherwise = amountCard n k xs
```

Furthermore as is noted by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066658/haskell-count-elements-in-a-list-tail-recursion/43067041?noredirect=1#comment73221992_43067041), you can easily convert your code to:

```
amountCard n c [] = n
amountCard n k (x:xs) = amountCard (if k == x then n + 1 else n) k xs
```

And now it obviously is *tail recursive*, since the body of the second clause contains only one call to the same function (with different arguments).

Comment: Just a side note, since `if-then-else` is an expression, you can use it to specify the correct argument without using a guard: `amountCard n k (x:xs) = amountCard (if k == x then n + 1 else n) k xs`.

Comment: @chepner: that is indeed a nice argument. I updated the answer with your node. Thanks.